# How to set up an IPSec VPN with failover on linux without virtual IP?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, failover

I need to set up a VPN connection using IPsec between a client system and our Linux server. There shall be a fallback in case of failure of the VPN endpoint, i.e. some sort of automatic failover.

From what I researched so far, it should be possible to configure, for example, StrongSWAN with a virtual IP (e.g. ClusterIP, keepalived) to provide this sort of failover. Sadly, virtual IPs don't work in my cloud setup. Is there another way to provide this sort of failover without using virtual IPs? Perhaps with DNS und multiple A records?

The failover does not need to be transparent.